# Java: query.setMaxResults(1); Causes javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements

Tags: java, jpa

When using  em.createQuery(rowLockQry).getSingleResult();

ERROR [2022-01-18 19:54:38,798] [ajp-/10.0.53.72:8009-12] (AccountDaoImpl.java:3389) - Error occurred when fetching IndRowLock Value for SSP
javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:297)
at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler$3.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:258)
How to handle this? I thought get single result should only return 1 record (max)

```
public DBProc_CalcSSPSettingsPrBean getSspIndRowLockVal(String custAcctNbr) {
        try {
            LOGGER.debug("Entering AccountDaoImpl: getSspIndRowLockValgetSspIndRowLockVal");
            CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<DBProc_CalcSSPSettingsPrBean> rowLockQry = cb
                    .createQuery(DBProc_CalcSSPSettingsPrBean.class);

            Root<PsfsPaAcctSspTb> root = rowLockQry.from(PsfsPaAcctSspTb.class);
            Join<PsfsPaAcctSspTb, PsfsAcctSspTb> acctSspTb = root
                    .join("psfsAcctSspTbs");
            Join<PsfsAcctSspTb, PsfsCustAcctTb> custAcct = acctSspTb
                    .join("psfsCustAcctTb");

            rowLockQry.multiselect(acctSspTb.get("indRowLock"));

            rowLockQry
                    .where(cb.equal(custAcct.get("nbrCustAcct"), custAcctNbr));
            DBProc_CalcSSPSettingsPrBean sspIndRowLock = em.createQuery(
                    rowLockQry).getSingleResult();
            LOGGER.debug("Exit AccountDaoImpl: getSspIndRowLockVal");
            return sspIndRowLock;

        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
            LOGGER.debug("Exit AccountDaoImpl: getSspIndRowLockVal");
            return null;
        } 
        
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(
                    "Error occurred when fetching IndRowLock Value for SSP", e);
        }
        LOGGER.debug("Exit AccountDaoImpl: getSspIndRowLockVal");
        return null;

    }

    
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T> T getSingleResult(Query query) {
        LOGGER.debug("Entering AccountDaoImpl: getSingleResult");
        query.setMaxResults(1);
        List<?> list = query.getResultList();
        if (list == null || list.size() == 0) {
            LOGGER.debug("Exit AccountDaoImpl: getSingleResult");
            return null;
        }
        LOGGER.debug("Exit AccountDaoImpl: getSingleResult");
        return (T) list.get(0);
    }'''
```

Comment: I was thinking to catch and print the record. But Why is this error throw if I set it to max 1?

Comment: getSingleResult is likely (provider dependent) not using the maxRows hint. Queries using getSingleResult are intended to only return a single result and force exceptions if there is more than one - they are meant for find by unique identifier queries and that hint would hinder their ability to throw an exception on duplicates being found. You already have a getSingleResult method that gets a list and returns the first element - that is what most do for queries of this nature anyway.

Comment: @Chris Why don't you add this as the answer? I don't like reading unanswered question that have the answer in the comment